# Why do browsers only display .jpg images and never .jpeg ones?

Tags: images, browsers

I'm testing the speed of my CDN network by directly browsing to the addresses of images that are stored on it. Some of these images are in `jpg` format while others are in `jpeg` format.

I've noticed that when i browse the address of a `jpg` file the image is always displayed by default. When i check the `network` tab of the `inspect` menu in `google chrome` or similar browsers i also see that the response is always displayed under the response type `img`. However when its a `jpeg` file the browser always downloads it as a document by default and the response can only be found under the `doc` response type. So the browser doesn't treat it as an image at all, even though it is.

So why is this the case? Aren't `jpg` and `jpeg` pretty much the same thing?

Comment: If you don't mind, try file-renaming one of your `jpeg` files to be `jpg`, then try loading it through the CDN again. If the browser displays it normally as a `jpg`, that would confirm my suspicion that it's not about the file itself, it's about the server software (the CDN's built-in software) reading the file extensions and serving them up with different HTTP headers. Perhaps it knows it needs to serve `jpg` "as an image", but just sees `jpeg` as a generic "file". If so, it may be a [mime-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types) thing.

Comment: There is no "jpg format while others are in jpeg format.". There is a single format, not 2, it is called JPEG. As for the extensions, it is only because of bad OS that one needs to use `.jpg` and this was long ago. There is really no reason today to continue doing that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thia is likely due to the way the CDN is set up.  When an object is sent by the web server, the server typically asvisises the "mime type" - a string advising the kind of object - to the browser to encourage the browser to handle it in an appropriate way.

It sounds like the CDN does not have a mapping for ".jpeg".  (Of-course, it could also be the CDN has a mapping and your computer is interpretting it differently).

Comment: I'm on my cell, so havn't tried it properly, but try pasting the urls into https://fabianstiehle.com/mimetype/ which I think will return the mime type.

Comment: I don't think CDNs typically control the mime type. They just pass the mime type from the origin server along.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller - I largely agree - but  if the objects live in the CDN as appears to be the case here per the users first sentence (he specifically states images are stored), the CDN is a web server.

Comment: @davidgo i'm using AWS s3 and cloudfront to serve the images. So the images are stored in s3 and cached in cloudfront.

Comment: @Maurice - In that case, yes, the CDN is likely  just passing through the S3 header.  I've not played with this, but I infer from https://petersmith.org/blog/2017/05/31/mime-types-on-asw-s3/ that whatever is uploading the ".jpeg" files to S3 is not setting the mime-type.

Comment: @davidgo `whatever is uploading the ".jpeg" files to S3 is not setting the mime-type`. All the images are uploaded through my spring boot web application which uses classes/methods from the AWS sdk for java to upload the file. But the content type is never explicitly set so i'm going to change that first and then test whether the content type is correct. As of now the content type of the uploaded images is `application/xml` according to the tool of `fabiansthiele.com` you suggested.

Comment: @davidgo i just confirmed that the browser issue was caused because my application did not set the mimetype. I've changed the code so that the mimetype is included on each upload and now the image is displayed normally again, Thank you!